# You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently using AuthRoute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I have an authroute that simply redirect the user back to login page using a flag, but I got warning of `You tried to redirect to the same route`.

here is my authroute component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getInfo } from '../../redux/user.redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

@withRouter
@connect(state=>state.user,
    {getInfo}
)
class AuthRoute extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {

        const publicList = ['/login', '/register']
        const { pathname } = this.props.location

        //if user hit login or register route don't do anything
        if(publicList.indexOf(pathname)>-1){
            return null
        }
        this.props.getInfo()
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            {this.props.redirectTo?<Redirect to={this.props.redirectTo} />:''}
        </div>
    }
}

export default AuthRoute
```

My redux file

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { getRedirectPath } from '../util'

const LOGIN_SUCESS = 'LOGIN_SUCESS'
const LOAD_DATA = 'LOAD_DATA'
const AUTH_FALSE = 'AUTH_FALSE'

const initState = {
    redirectTo: '',
    isAuth: false,
    msg: '',
    user: '',
    type: ''
}

//reducers
export function user(state=initState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case LOGIN_SUCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload,
                msg: '',
                isAuth: true,
                redirectTo: getRedirectPath(action.payload)
            }
        case LOAD_DATA:
            return {...state, ...action.payload}
        case AUTH_FALSE:
            return {...state, redirectTo: '/login'}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export function getInfo(){
    return dispatch=>{
        axios.get('/user/info')
            .then(res=>{
                if(res.status===200&&res.data.code===0){
                    dispatch({
                        type:LOGIN_SUCESS,
                        payload: res.data.data
                    })
                }else{
                    dispatch({type: AUTH_FALSE})
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Call a request using getInfo method with a cookie, if the user is not found, change the state to have a redirectTo value. Anything I did wrong with this? I tried to move the axios call in the componentDidMount, and use `this.history.push(this.props.redirectTo)` in the callback, it doesn't have that error, strange.

Comment: Can you post code for the ```getRedirectPath()``` function and also the action payload?

Comment: that doesn't matter, it return two role in string only. https://pastebin.com/PS1bpAws